# Visual Studio Coded's Terminal not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

### Issue Description

Upon launching VS Code, the Terminal displays "PTY HOST" in the bottom bar. Unfortunately, the Terminal seems unresponsive, preventing me from executing commands. I've restarted VS Code, closed and reopened the project, and checked for updates, but the issue persists.

### Problem Details

- **Symptoms:** Terminal shows "PTY HOST," but no commands can be executed.
- **Actions Taken:** Restarted VS Code, reopened project, checked for updates.

### Environment Information

- **VS Code Version:** last version
- **Operating System:** windows11

### Request for Assistance

Seeking guidance on troubleshooting and resolving the "PTY HOST" Terminal issue in VS Code. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: First of all, this question is not programming related and does not belong to StackOverflow. I recommend to ask this at [su]. But even there, I guess you will get more help if you describe, how you have configured your terminal (i.e. how you start the command- or powershell), and what VSC version you are using.